# Is it possible to buy gas cartridges on a Sunday in Reykjavik?

Tags: stoves, iceland, canister-stoves

I'm visiting Iceland this august, will be arriving in Reykjavik. Since it's not possible to bring gas cartridges with me, I'll need to buy them there. I'll be arriving on a sunday. Is it possible to buy gas cartridges like [here](http://www.buy-camping-gas.co.uk/coleman/coleman-100-gas-cartridge) somewhere in Reykjavik on a sunday, or are all stores closed on sundays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Googled and found there is a least one store (top return) that is open daily from 9AM to 5PM.  It also offers 24/7 pickup and drop off of rental supplies.  So yes you can get [gas cartridges](https://www.iceland-camping-equipment.com/collections/iceland-stove-gas-fuel-rental/products/gas-canister-fuel-iceland) on a Sunday in Reykjavik.

Their address is as follows:

Barónsstígur 5

101 Reykjavik - Iceland

Tel. +354 647 0569

Answer (score 1):

On my last trip to Iceland I got the tip to look around at the air port for gas cartridges. Often people who are leaving drop their stuff there.

Also hostels might be a good place to search for.
The biggest selection I probably saw, was at the campsite in Reykjavik.